# File permissions in Linux assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, permissions, system-calls

I'm trying to get information about file permissions. I am using the sys_access system call. Here is my code snippet:

```
mov eax, 33 
mov ebx, fileName 
mov ecx, 1 
int 80h 

cmp eax, 0 
jl .error
```

If `eax` is -1 there is an error, and I am not getting one, but I need to check all the permissions of the file (owner, group, others). How do I do that?

Comment: `access(2)` doesn't return the file permissions. It tests whether the current process has permissions specified in the second argument.

Comment: To get the permissions, use `stat(2)`. It returns a structure with information about the file, including the permission mode.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. Now i'm trying to change those permissions using chmod(), but when I'm setting the mod using tags that I've found here:  [link] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/chmod.htm), they kinda do not ework ad i want. When i set ecx to 00400 | 00200 it sets the owner to read and write and also (don not know why) guest is set that it can write. Though when I use  00400 | 00200 | 00040 its sets both read and write. Can you help me maybe with this also?

Comment: Try asking a new question for that.

Comment: Well, basically all would be the same (almost - i.e. the title), so I thought that would not be a good choice.

Comment: I can't see a reason why that would set other to write. It should just be owner = read-write, group and other = none.

Comment: yeah that's what i thought but it doesn't work that way. I also tried to pop ecx before setting it and also - same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the kernel function `sys_newstat` (No. 106 - look at [this table](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html)) to get the file permissions. The structure `stat` is a never ending horror, but the following example works at least on my Debian Wheezy 64 bit (NASM, 32-bit and 64-bit modes):

```
SECTION .data

    filename        db '/root'          ; Just an example, can be replaced with any name
    filename_len    equ $ - filename    ; Length of filename
                    db 0                ; Terminator for `Int 80h / EAX = 106`
    perm_out        db 'Permissions: '
    perm            db 'drwxrwxrwx'
    perm_len        equ $ - perm        ; Index of last character in `perm`
    lf              db 10
    perm_out_len    equ $ - perm_out    ; Length of `Permissions: ...\n`

SECTION .bss
    stat resb 256               ; Way too much, but size is variable depending on OS

SECTION .text
global _start

_start:

    mov eax,4                   ; sys-out
    mov edx,filename_len        ; length of string to print
    mov ecx,filename            ; Pointer to string
    mov ebx,1                   ; StdOut
    int 0x80                    ; Call kernel

    mov eax,4                   ; sys-out
    mov edx,1                   ; Length of string to print
    mov ecx, lf                 ; Pointer to string
    mov ebx,1                   ; StdOut
    int 0x80                    ; Call kernel

    mov eax, 106                ; sys_newstat
    mov ebx, filename           ; Pointer to ASCIIZ file-name
    mov ecx, stat               ; Pointer to structure stat
    int 80h

    test eax, eax
    jz .noerr
    mov eax,1                   ; sys_exit
    mov ebx,1                   ; Exit code, 1=not normal
    int 0x80                    ; Call kernel
    .noerr:

    movzx eax, word [stat + 8]  ; st_mode (/usr/include/asm/stat.h)
    mov ebx, perm_len

    ; rwx bits
    mov ecx, 9
    .L1:
    sub ebx, 1
    shr eax, 1
    jc .J1
    mov byte [perm + ebx], '-'
    .J1:
    loop .L1

    ; directory bit
    sub ebx, 1
    shr eax, 6
    jc .J2
    mov byte [perm + ebx], '-'
    .J2:

    mov eax,4                   ; sys-out
    mov edx,perm_out_len        ; Length of string to print
    mov ecx,perm_out            ; Pointer to string
    mov ebx,1                   ; StdOut
    int 0x80                    ; Call kernel

    mov eax,1                   ; sys_exit
    mov ebx,0                   ; Exit code, 0=normal
    int 0x80                    ; Call kernel
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've managed to get stat() working properly. Now I'm stuck with problem that i mentioned in the comment above. Now i want to change permissions of that file (please look up in the comments).

Comment: @TreeZ: Ask a new question, tell us assembler, linker and the Linux version and show a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - and maybe I will work on it tomorrow ;-)